# If you intend to handle the same path in multiple methods Spring

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Im using spring MVC.

My Controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approval/pendingescort", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPendingEscort(Model model) {

    log.debug("Received request to show Pending Escorts");

// Retrieve all pending escort details by delegating the call to Servicelayer
    List<EscortRegistration> pendingEscortdetails = approvalService.getAllPendingEscort();

// Attach zones to the Model
     model.addAttribute("pendingEscortdetails", pendingEscortdetails);

// This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/pendingescort.jsp
    return "pendingescort";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/approval/pendingescort/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addEscort(@RequestParam(value="mobileno", required=true) String mobileno,Model model) {

    log.debug("Received request to Accept Escort Request");

        // Call ZonedetailsService to do the actual Updating
        approvalService.approveEscortRequest(mobileno);

        // Add mobile reference to Model
        model.addAttribute("mobileno", mobileno);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addedescortpage.jsp
        return "pendingescort";
}
```

and my JSP Is :

```
<tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${pendingEscortdetails}" var="escort">
                    <c:url var="editUrl" value="/efmfm/main/approval/pendingescort/success?mobileno=${escort.mobilenumber}" />
                    <c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/efmfm/main/approval/pendingescort/delete?mobileno=${escort.mobilenumber}" />
                    <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${escort.mobilenumber}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${escort.imei}" /></td>
                <td>    <a href="${editUrl}" class="approv">Approve</a> 

                    <!--  <td>Approve</td> -->
                    <a href="${deleteUrl}" class="approv">Reject</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody
```

when i click to approve its sending to success page. i want to bring this to previous page with refresh.
Can any one solve my problem.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: <a href="${editUrl}" class="approv">Approve</a> when i try to approve the value its redirecting to another success page but its not bring back to previous page.

Comment: Escorts and mobile numbers good times. Mabye look at defining a model and view redirect. ModelAndView nextView = new ModselAndView("redirect:pendingEscortdetails");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
return "redirect:../../../approval/pendingescort";
```

Instead of

```
return "pendingescort";
```

Comment: its redirecting this page http://localhost:8080/efmfm-app/approval/pendingescort?mobileno=123456789  actual is http://localhost:8080/efmfm-app/efmfm/main/approval/pendingescort  moreover in jsp i m sending request as <c:url var="editUrl" value="/efmfm/main/approval/pendingescort/success?mobileno=${escort.mobilenumber}" />

Comment: edited answer. but how pendingescort view resolves to different jsp(You mentioned in your code).

Comment: Could you provide views.xml above for more clarification\

Comment: there are many ways to redirect . 1.) you can redirect from controller 2.) redirect from the resolved jsp 3.) make a ajax call and then use window.loction.href = location.href; in the success.

Answer (score 0):

First: I guess you need to use `"../.."`

```
return "redirect:../../../approval/pendingescort";
```

One more doubt. Are you using tiles??

Comment: @BashaGhouse : if my answer has helped you please mark it correct.